# 'JoinableQueue' object is not iterable

Tags: python, for-loop, queue, multiprocessing

Assuming i have a queue:

```
myqueue = multiporcessing.JoinableQueue()
```

In my code, the parent process puts all the object (e.g. a string) into `myqueue`, 'myqueue' will be shared by child processes, and the child process will need to check if an object (e.g. xxx) is in `myqueue`, I tried to use:

```
if xxx in [y for y in myqueue]
```

but it gives me the error like:

```
'JoinableQueue' object is not iterable
```

My question is, is there any other way I can use to get what I want as above? Or any way I can use to check if an object is still in the queue?

The reason for checking the shared queue is that the objects in the queue is interdependence, and every object has some status such as 'running', 'waiting', 'completed'. For example, object 'a' has a dependency 'A', 'A' and 'a' will be put into the queue by parent process(before child process kick-off), when a child process gets 'a' from the queue, it needs to check the status of 'A', if the status of 'A' is still 'waiting', then 'a' will be put back into the queue unless 'A' is 'completed'. In other words, 'A' is not in myqueue anymore.

Comment: i think the reason you can't iterate over it is that because it was designed to be shared by multiple processes, the collection of items underneath would not be consistent. why do you need to check for existence of an object ? what exactly is your code trying to achieve ?

Comment: You can use `list(xs)` instead of `[x for x in xs]`.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to create a set of objects that are being processed and remove them when task is done? As iterating over job queue might affect the order of executed tasks.

Comment: Hi omu_negru, the reason is that the objects in the queue is interdependence, and every object has some status such as 'running', 'waiting', 'completed'. for example, object 'a' has a dependency 'A', 'A' and 'a' will be put into the queue by parent process(before child process kick-off), when a child process gets 'a' from the queue, it needs to check the status of 'A', if the status of 'A' is still 'waiting', then 'a' will be put back into the queue unless 'A' is 'completed', in other words, 'A' is not in myqueue anymore.

Comment: I think you are doing it wrong: `a` shouldn't be on the queue until it is ready to be processed. You should make `A` add `a` to the queue once it has been completed.

Comment: Thanks @DouglasLeeder, that means i will need to queue all the object like A first, it's complicated though since A could have dependencies as well...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JoinableQueue` doesn't support peeking of any kind (unless you count `empty`/`full`).

Depending on what you want to do with the collection in addition, you could need a different object to store your queue in. However, there are two possible solutions:

1. If you know no other process will touch the queue while you are checking this, you could `get` every object, see if what you were looking for was there, then `put` them back in the same order.
2. Otherwise, if the child is the only process that will ever `get` objects, you could put the objects in another temporary queue.

The former should be straightforward to implement. The latter could be something like:

```
class QueueView:
    def __init__(self, joinable):
        self.joinable = joinable
        self.other = collections.deque()
    def get(self, block=True, timeout=None):
        if self.other:
            return self.other.popleft()
        self.joinable.get(block, timeout)
    def __contains__(self, item):
        if item in self.other:
            return True
        try:
            while True:
                o = self.joinable.get(block=False)
                self.other.append(o)
        except Queue.Empty:
            pass
        return item in self.other
```

Only one process should see the `QueueView` object and `get` anything from the `JoinableQueue` through the view object. Any number of processes can `put` things in the `JoinableQueue`.

Comment: i think if the queue is filled with lots of tasks, the solution 1 will have performance issue, i.e. to execute one task, the queue will be 'get' and 'put'

Comment: @3quanfeng, if you are concerned about performance (not that you [necessarily should](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization)), solution 2 + a set would likely be the best option. I.e. add another member `self.set` to `QueueView`, which you also keep up to date and use for the `in` queries in `__contains__`.